# Dapper Multi mapping doesn't map correct

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to map two entities using Dapper. It's like this:

You have table Movie:
MovieID,
Runtime,
Description,
Title,
Director,
Genres

And table Projection:
ProjectionID,
Time,
Price, 
Hall, 
MovieID

Movie has a list of Projections (fore each movie one or more projections)

After connection the result list for movies with their projections is just the FIRST movie and ALL the records from projection.

Basically, Movie1 has two Projections Movie2 has three Projections it returns list of five movies and all of them are the first movie and all of them have five projections.

Can someone help me where do I make a mistake?

```
public List<Movie> ReturnMovieProjections()
{
    var list = new List<Movie>();
    var sql = "SELECT " +
                        "m.MovieID, " +
                        "m.Runtime, " +
                        "m.Description, " +
                        "m.Title, " +
                        "m.Director, " +
                        "m.Genres, " +
                        "p.MovieID, " +
                        "p.ProjectionID, " +
                        "p.Time, " +
                        "p.Price, " +
                        "p.Hall " +
                  "FROM Movie AS m INNER JOIN Projection AS p " +
                    "ON m.MovieID = p.MovieID " +
                  "WHERE p.MovieID = m.MovieID";

     using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString("CinemaDB")))
     {
         var movieDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Movie>();
         list = connection.Query<Movie, Projection, Movie>(
         sql, (movie, projection) =>
         {
             Movie movieEntry;
             if (!movieDictionary.TryGetValue(movie.MovieID, out movieEntry))
             {
                 movieEntry = movie;
                 movieEntry.Projections = new List<Projection>();
                 movieDictionary.Add(movieEntry.MovieID, movieEntry);
             }
             movieEntry.Projections.Add(projection);
             return movieEntry;
         },
         splitOn: "p.MovieID").AsList();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the dictionary values and not the IEnumerable obtained by Dapper.
That value will always contain all the 5 records produced by the query

Also there is no need to add a WHERE condition equal to the JOIN statement

```
var sql = "SELECT " +
                "m.MovieID, " +
                "m.Runtime, " +
                "m.Description, " +
                "m.Title, " +
                "m.Director, " +
                "m.Genres, " +
                "p.MovieID, " +
                "p.ProjectionID, " +
                "p.Time, " +
                "p.Price, " +
                "p.Hall " +
          "FROM Movie AS m INNER JOIN Projection AS p " +
            "ON m.MovieID = p.MovieID ";
 using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString("CinemaDB")))
{
    var movieDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Movie>();
    list = connection.Query<Movie, Projection, Movie>(sql, (movie, projection) =>
    {
         Movie movieEntry = null;
         if (!movieDictionary.TryGetValue(movie.MovieID, out movieEntry))
         {
             movieEntry = movie;
             movieEntry.Projections = new List<Projection>();
             movieDictionary.Add(movieEntry.MovieID, movieEntry);
         }
         movieEntry.Projections.Add(projection);
         return movie; // return the same instance passed by Dapper.
    },splitOn: "p.MovieID");
}
return movieDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. I have removed WHERE part of the sql, and returned result like this: var result = movieDictionary.Values.ToList();
return result;                                                                                                                            Now I have only one movie with 5 projecetions. I think I didn't get the Second part of your answer.  Perhaps you can try to explain it to me again. Sorry and thanx.